# Android App get killed in HUAWEI phone

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

Few days ago I moved to HUAWEI P9 phone and try to keep developing my app.
My new problem (have not seen it on other devices..) is that my app is getting killed after the screen turns off (not immeditaely but after a minute or too).

To be sure that the issue is not related to my application, I created the simple "hello world" application from the android studio, and the behavior is exactly the same.

I'm running Android 6.0 (API 23) on my device.

Any Idea why even the simplest app is getting killed after the screen is turned off?

Thanks!
Lior

Comment: logcat will bring you one step closer, please post the logs!

Comment: Need more information here, anyways, I believe you already know this, but try to use the latest Android Studio

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your app in the 'protect application with battery saver' (under battery's option).

Hope this helps